# Регулярное выражение: N по счёту совпадение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярного выражения взять текст от начала, до 5-ой запятой (по порядку отсчитывая от начала)

```
688160442,'Москва','проспект Маршала Жукова','22к3','3','1','42',NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1918274,1,'2021-12-17 23:13:35','2021-12-17 23:21:04','2021-12-17 23:13:35','2021-12-17 23:56:57','2021-12-17 23:41:58','2021-12-17 23:22:34','2021-12-18 00:00:30',30,55,65,61,55.776674,37.483984,'2021-12-17 23:12:43',NULL,NULL,NULL,'92915ab1-c846-4f70-b061-650002e30ea1','211217-427662',0,'RUB',1858,NULL,1858,NULL,1,2,'EatsPayments',2,NULL,NULL,NULL,2835848,'30169799',108268748,NULL
```

Что бы взять:

```
688160442,'Москва','проспект Маршала Жукова','22к3','3',
```

И заменить на пустоту, в результате получить нужно:

```
'1','42',NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1918274,1,'2021-12-17 23:13:35','2021-12-17 23:21:04','2021-12-17 23:13:35','2021-12-17 23:56:57','2021-12-17 23:41:58','2021-12-17 23:22:34','2021-12-18 00:00:30',30,55,65,61,55.776674,37.483984,'2021-12-17 23:12:43',NULL,NULL,NULL,'92915ab1-c846-4f70-b061-650002e30ea1','211217-427662',0,'RUB',1858,NULL,1858,NULL,1,2,'EatsPayments',2,NULL,NULL,NULL,2835848,'30169799',108268748,NULL
```

А потом, другим регулярным выражением, пропустить две запятых, и удалить(заменить на пустоту) все что осталось после, что бы получилось:

```
'1','42',NULL
```

Comment: Так Вам в итоге надо получить две строки или только последнюю? Какой язык программирования?

Comment: И то и другое - по отдельности

Comment: Чистые регулярные выражения, буду использовать в txt редакторах

Comment: s/^((?:.*?,){5})// - первое    s/^((?:.*?,){2})// - второе. Я не понял откуда '1','42',NULL - тут NULL? это в стиле perl - замена

Comment: '1','42',NULL  - это начальная часть после первой регулярки, нужно пропустить две запятых, и удалить всё что после.

Comment: то есть как можно пропустить первые две запятые, а всё что после (пропущенного, удалить)?

Comment: s/^((?:.*?,){2}.*?),//

Comment: а как сделать что бы при замене регулярки на пустоту, сбывалось последнее значение?

Comment: s/^((?:.*?,){2}.*?),/$1/  - если я правильно понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись одним выражением, например:

```
^(?:[^,]+,){5}((?:[^,]+,){2}[^,]+)(?:.+)
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/JRoqhm/1)

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите, почему то когда меняю на 11, например, перестает работать.
^(?:[^,]+,){11}((?:[^,]+,){2}[^,]+)(?:.+)

Comment: В вопросе же писали "И то и другое - по отдельности" ??? :))

Comment: @АлексейСердюк на regex101 все работает и с 11 и с 25. Вероятно, имеют место быть особенности вашей реализации